# optimization possibilities for known loop trip counts

Tags: optimization, language-agnostic, compiler-construction

What can a compiler do for optimization if it knows the loop trip count of a loop? Loop unrolling is one.What are others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Avoidance of loop-skip-check on loop entry (many modern languages allow loops to have zero iterations, but you have to check on entry)
- Better SIMDization (blocking the loop iterations into chunks processable by small vectors)
- Removal of subscript range checking (or diagnosis of error) (for those languages that insist)

Comment: If one knows the range of the index variable, one knows the range of an index expression.  For instance, if 0<i<4 and  x[3*i+6] is a subscript, then 6<=3*i+6<=30.  So if x has dimension larger than 30, an out-of-range subscript cannot occur, and you don't need to check.  (C simply doesn't check and  you get garbage if the index value is too big).